# Openshift node app error when restarting

Tags: node.js, sockets, openshift

I have a node/socket.io chat app hosted on openshift, and while it starts correctly if i ssh into the server and do "node main.js" (where main.js is the server script that starts the chat), I can't start the app on the server by web interface, where it would go on automatically; If i just start the app by ssh, it would stop working as soon as i exit the terminal.

I get this error when starting the app by the web interface:

```
    Starting Node.js application...
    Application is already stopped.
    Warning! Could not start Node.js application!
    Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/57003fbe7628e1491d00011e/nodejs
```

In case it's relevant, my package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "rainychat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "rainychat, my chat app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.5",
    "validator": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "JG",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And here you can see the files of the app by ftp:
[image]

I can't decode what that error means...

My main.js code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html'); // /home/redadmin/public_html/rainychat.com
    console.log('enviado');
});

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

http.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
//... More code
```

Comment: Please post errors as plain text in the body of your question. These screenshots are highly distracting and add little in the way of clarity to your question.

Comment: Can you use a Node module like [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to launch and persist your process? That's a better way to do it.

Comment: @tadman Uh, sure, posted the error in the body instead of picture. But i have no idea how to use pm2, and i'd prefer not to keep adding modules instead of finding the error, which is probably very simple

Comment: The problem with screenshots is they're images, not text, and are often really hard to read. `pm2` is the best way to launch and keep a process running. There's really no other way to do this without writing something exactly like `pm2` yourself, which is considerable amounts of work.

Comment: Is that your complete `package.json` or just a part of it? If that's the whole thing it's not [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: That is the complete package.json, written per what it says here: https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/

Comment: Their example is a *part* of it, not the whole thing.

Comment: I modified my post. Edited the package.json and now the error changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating a new Node project, start with `npm init` to create the `package.json` file. You can add the `--auto` option to give it safe defaults.

Remember, the JSON file must be valid JSON, so test it with `jsonlint` or a tool like [an online validator](http://jsonlint.com).

Any dependencies your project has should be spelled out in the package file. This is done automatically with things like `npm install express --save`.

Comment: I modified my package.json and now the error changed. I edited my post

Comment: Seems like you're on to a different problem now.