# Warning! Could not stop Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, openshift, nodes

i'm using openshift to host my discord bot. the bot was not responding to commands so i went to the .rhcloud.com witch was takeing way to long to lode so i whent into my dashbord and clicked restart and it gave me this error

```
Stopping Node.js application...
Warning! Could not stop Node.js application!
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/57af65500c1e669c9f000142/nodejs
```

i've tried to ssh into the server and tried to do it manually but the server just hangs when i do `gear restart` even when i have ran `killall node` and then `gear start` it still just hangs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380606/openshift-node-app-error-when-restarting ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 'Could not stop...' error, force stopping app helped.

```
rhc app-force-stop <app-name>
rhc app-start <app-name>
```

Though stil have no clue why app went to hung state.